# How do I solve this specific type of linear system?

Tags: matlab, system, linear-algebra

I've been having trouble solving the system of linear equations in order to obtain X.

It looks like this;

```
A* ([4;0] + X*([4; 3] - [4;0])) = B
```

Given `A = [-1 0; 0 -1; 1 1]` and `B = [0; 0; 5]`.

The solution I'm expecting is one that states that the largest X possible would be 1/3. In other words, X is a scalar which would satisfy the condition.

Comment: What answer do you get? What answer do you expect? Can you separate the code from the prose? AT <= B, so T = A\B is not valid matlab.

Comment: Is "<=" less than or equal to or your attempt at an arrow? Please edit your question. Actual instances of `A` and `B` and your expected `T` (or `X`) would clarify things.

Comment: Is `([4;0] + X*([4; 3] - [4;0]))`? right? Doesn't that just simplify to `[4;3*X]`?

Comment: Exactly that! But how would I do that in matlab? How would I find the largest value of X which satisfies the =B constraint?

Comment: As far as I can see,  you can't get anything which is exactly = B, but you can find the maximum of `X` which keeps all of `A* ([4;0] + X*([4; 3] - [4;0]))` less than B - is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would like my code to do!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Symbolic Toolbox you can do something like:

```
A = [-1 0; 0 -1; 1 1];
B = [0;0;5];
syms X positive;

test = A*([4;0] + X*([4; 3] - [4;0]))-B;

solve(test<0,X);
```

This will give you a range (0, 1/3) in which `test<0` is true. Or in this case you can just solve `test(3)==0` for the exact answer.

Otherwise, you can write a function which evaluates whether your conditions are met:

```
F = @(X)all(A*([4;0]+X*([4;3]-[4;0]))<B)
```

Then write some code to manually evaluate F(X) for different X until you get within some threshold value of the max value of X.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to that Toolbox. How would I make it such that it loops in an efficient manner, since X can take decimal values?

Comment: Usually you do something like start with a given range and a step (say 0 to 1 in 0.1 steps), find approximately where the crossover happens (e.g. 0.3 will work and 0.4 won't), and then examine that range in a smaller step (0.3 to 0.4 in 0.01 steps), and so on until your step value goes below some threshold you set.